# Importing a Bib file in IEEE Trans

Tags: ieeetran

Can I import a my bib file IEEE Trans by simply typing between the `\begin{thebibliography}` and `\end{thebibliography}` tags `\input{./Master.bib}` or am I forced to use this style as suggested in [IEEE Trans template here](https://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/author_templates.html#sect1)?

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{IEEEhowto:kopka}
H.~Kopka and P.~W. Daly, \emph{A Guide to \LaTeX}, 3rd~ed.\hskip 1em plus
  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Harlow, England: Addison-Wesley, 1999.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: You can but then you need to adjust all items one by one manually to comply with the style

Comment: If you literally mean to `\input` the .bib file, it won't work correctly, since a .bib file isn't TeX code at all. It's bibtex's job to convert the .bib and .aux files' content into a .bbl, which is the TeX code you see in the final bibliography.

Comment: This comes down to 'How does BibTeX work?'. I've marked as a dupe of a general question in the same area, as to be honest you might be best simply reading an intro text.